# Erro ao exibir alert com letras de utf-8

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript-eventos

Bom eu estou fazendo lançando um alert para o usuário informando um erro ao importar um arquivo, entretanto todos os caracteres de utf-8 estão com problema de exibição, eu estou mandando uma viewbag da minha controller, onde eu estou usando globalization

```
 ViewBag.Message = string.Format("A data usada em periodo de apuração na linha {0} esta errada", linha, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR"));
```

o código no view esta assim

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
@if (ViewBag.Message != null)
{
    <script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            alert("@ViewBag.Message");
            html: true
        };
    </script>
}
```

[image: abaixo esta como a imagem é exibida]

Comment: Você já tentou realizar a inclusão do `alert` com o `charset` em **Windows 1252**? Atualmente tenho realizado a utilização apenas do `windows1252` e tem funcionado sem problemas.

Comment: Eu testei e o mesmo erro continua

Comment: Certo, então acredito que o erro esteja relacionado ao **C#**,  antes mesmo de trazer para o **HTML**, dá uma verificada em como ele está gerando o `@ViewBag`.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar o código abaixo:

alert('@Html.Raw(@ViewData["Message "])')

Isso deve funcionar para você